# birt increment values in a report based on unique key

Tags: sql, report, reporting, birt

I've managed to get the following output from a simple select statement:

```
SELECT DAILY.KEY,DAILY.TIMESTAMP,DAILY.LOG
FROM DAILY 
ORDER BY DAILY.SEQUENCE

    KEY      ,TIMESTAMP           , LOG
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_4 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_C 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_9 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, OPTION_20 
    index_235,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_6 
    index_235,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_A 
    index_235,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_6 
    index_235,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, OPTION_10 
    index_233,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_7 
    index_233,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_A 
    index_233,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_7 
    index_231,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_4 
    index_231,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_C 
    index_231,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_8 
    index_232,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_4 
    index_232,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_C 
    index_232,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_9
```

However, am not sure how to process this data before creating my report.

I basically need to create counts for each unique sequence. 
but am having trouble correlating each option..
ie for the KEY

```
    KEY      ,TIMESTAMP           , LOG
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MAIN_4 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, MENU_C 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, SUBMENU_9 
    index_230,Oct 2, 2013 11:02 AM, OPTION_20
```

Should increment these values in a report:

```
MAIN_4(+1) +- MENU_C(+1) +-- SUBMENU_9(+1) +-- OPTION_20 (+1)
```

Where the entire report would end up as follows:

```
MAIN_1  +- MENU_A(13)+-  SUBMENU_1(6)+- OPTION_1  (1)
        |            |               +- OPTION_2  (0)
        |            |               +- OPTION_3  (5)
        |            +-  SUBMENU_2(7)+- OPTION_1  (4)
        |                            +- OPTION_2  (3)
        |                            +- OPTION_3  (0)
        +- MENU_B(1) +-  SUBMENU_1(1)+- OPTION_1 (1)
                                     +- OPTION_2 (0)
         .                           +- OPTION_3 (0)
         .
         .

MAIN_2  +- MENU_A(1) +-  SUBMENU_1(1)+- OPTION_1  (1)
        |
etc...
```

Any pointers or recommendations on how to do this are appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed column to give a value of 1 to eaqch of your rows of data.  You can do math on the values, pretty much any place you want to get the best results for your report.

I this image I am giving the value of 1 to a new field "All" for every row in the data set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time to look!.. I'll look into this right away and let you know!

Comment: By the way, I found an interesting sql select to put the rows on the same line.
        
`code`select DAILY.KEY
`code`,LISTAGG(DAILY.LOG,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DAILY.ID)  AS     LOGTAGS
`code`from DAILY 
`code`GROUP BY DAILY.KEY

which produces something like this:
`code`KEY      , LOGTAGS
`code`index_230, MAIN_4,MENU_C,SUBMENU_9,OPTION_20